# How to nest Tab views in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xaml, xamarin, mobile, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am trying to create this layout in Xamarin XAML but I cannot figure out how to combine TabView within a TabView. I want 3 main tabs in the bottom and for each page 1-2 subtabs. On each subtab I will need to have a ScrollView(I think thats the right element to use) with list items, which makes it even more complex. Like this picture:

[image]

Any idea or guidance of how to achieve this?

Comment: You could probably use a main stackview with 3 children.  A horizontal stack for the top, scrollview, and then a horizontal stack for the bottom.  Put buttons into them.  When you click a button, have it swap in the necessary content and do whatever else you want to do.

Comment: Do you have any example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am trying to create this layout in Xamarin XAML but I cannot figure out how to combine TabView within a TabView.

If you want to do that, you could nest a `TabView` in Tabbed page.

`TabView`:https://github.com/chaosifier/TabView

Create three tab pages in views folder.

Tabbed Page:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<TabbedPage
x:Class="TabbedPageDemo.MainPage"
xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
xmlns:Views="clr-namespace:TabbedPageDemo.Views"
xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
BarBackgroundColor="Blue"
BarTextColor="White"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<Views:Tab1_Page Title="TAB1" />
<Views:Tab2_Page Title="TAB2" />
<Views:Tab3_Page Title="TAB3" />

</TabbedPage>
```

And then use TabView in you tab1 page.

Tab1_Page:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage
x:Class="TabbedPageDemo.Views.Tab1_Page"
xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Xam.Plugin.TabView;assembly=Xam.Plugin.TabView"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d">
<ContentPage.Content>
    <local:TabViewControl>
        <local:TabViewControl.ItemSource>
            <local:TabItem HeaderText="SUBTAB1">
                <StackLayout VerticalOptions="Start" Padding="10">
                    <Button
                    BackgroundColor="White"                    
                    Text="List Item"
                    TextColor="Black"/>
                </StackLayout>                                                
            </local:TabItem>
            <local:TabItem HeaderText="SUBTAB2">
                <Image Source="pink.jpg" />
            </local:TabItem>
        </local:TabViewControl.ItemSource>
    </local:TabViewControl>
</ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Please note, if you want to make the tabs in tabbed page in the bottom. Add the code below in your MainPage.

```
 On<Android>().SetToolbarPlacement(ToolbarPlacement.Bottom);
```

[image]

You could download the code sample from GitHub in TabbedPage_NestedTabView/TabbedPageDemo
https://github.com/WendyZang/Test.git