# Xamarin Forms - 2 tabbed page in the same view

Tags: xamarin

I new in Xamarin and I want to know if it is possible to have 2 tabbed pages (i dont know if this is the right terminology) in the same view.
I want something like that:

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nn5bK.jpg)

Some help will be appreciate.

Comment: Hey Tiago! You can do in Xamarin everything that you can do in native development. So if that page can be developed in native android in java or kotlin, you can also program it through Xamarin

Comment: You just need TabbedPage

 (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.tabbedpage?view=xamarin-forms)

Comment: For the image you provided, it seems to use two tabbed pages in one content page. We could not do that. But you could try to add nest tab views in tabbed page. Please check the link below. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59794811/how-to-nest-tab-views-in-xamarin-forms/59808213#59808213

Comment: @WendyZang-MSFT   Thanks for your reply. I will try to follow the link that you provided.

Comment: @Александр If you still have question about this, feel free to let us know~